# kubernetes operator, how to hide property value in describe

Tags: kubernetes-operator

I am writing a k8s operator. In my CR file, I want to get password and store it in secret. 
Everything works fine except this password gets printed on the screen when I describe my object `kubectl describe myKind myObject` is there any way to hide particular property from spec or at least show *** instead of actual value? just like secret it just shows bytes and not actual value.

Added line before my property `// +kubebuilder:validation:Format=password`. this add format: password in CRD file but when I describe myObject it still prints all Spec values on the console.

Edit: SO putting more light on this:

my **_types.go snipplet is:

```
    // DB username
    DbUser string `json:"dbUser,required"`

    // DB password
    // +kubebuilder:validation:Format=password
    DbPassword string `json:"dbPassword,required"`
```

so I am making k8s secret out of `dbUser` and `dbPassword`
I have another option to ask users to create a secret as pre-req but I am not happy with that approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is the said property? Can you share that part of your CR file alongside the validation format?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Added code  in question Please check

Comment: my bounty points gone and not got the answer too :(

Comment: There is [*+kubebuilder:printcolumn*](https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/markers/crd.html) annotation. It's documented to affect `kubectl get` output. I tried it with `format=password` but it still leaves the password in plain text even for `kubectl get`. `kubectl describe` only masks `coreV1.Secret` and that would mean a lot of changes such as implementing a custom ctrl. Another way you could try is by omitting `dbPassword` from the serialized json with a MarshalJSON method for your type that leaves it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT store passwords / tokens etc. in plain text in the CR. It will be visible to anyone with permissions to read the CR (no matter if `k describe` shows it or not).

I would recommend changing the CRD spec so users can reference their secret by name. Users will need to create a [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#secret-types) of type `opaque` then create a CR that looks something like this:

```
apiVersion: "grp/v1"
kind: "mykind"
metadata:
  name: "my-kind-cr"
  namespace: "default"
spec:
  secretName: mysecret
```

where the secret would look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: dbpassword
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
stringData:
    dbPassword: "my password"
```

Comment: secret are also not really a secrets are :(